# Screwed up Apache2 Config and now can't access Wordpress site

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, wordpress

One way or another, I messed up my `apache2` installation on a server that I am hosting a wordpress site on.

I believe I mostly got it back to normal, but when I try to access the site at `www.mydomain.com` where it was before, I get the following page.

[image]

Luckily, I saved my configuration file which is the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName mydomain.COM
   DocumentRoot /var/www
   DirectoryIndex index.php
   <Directory /var/www/>
      AllowOverride All
      Order Deny,Allow
      Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The wordpress files haven't been touched or moved and still reside in `/var/www/html`

I placed the config file above as `mydomain.conf` and ran the following

```
sudo a2ensite mydomain.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

but it doesn't change anything.

I am sure this is something simple, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I doubt it matters, but this is running on Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you check if PHP module is enabled?

Comment: If there's nothing in `/var/www/` but `/html/` and you were **not** going to `mydomain.com/html` before, then I think the first step is to set `DocumentRoot` to `/var/www/html/`.  Is there a `/var/www/.htaccess` hidden file?

Comment: That should be the root cause.

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici how do I check that

Comment: @DerfK I dont see a `.htaccess` file in `/var/www` or `/var/www/html`

Comment: First try to change DocumentRoot as @DerfK suggested.

Comment: I did the following in the following order, so I am not sure if just changing the document root was the entire solution or not. 1. I ran `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5` and then I changed the document root and it worked.

Comment: to check php modules  "php -m" command !